# Stripped Attributes with toJSON/toObject

Tags: javascript, sails.js, waterline

I have something like the following code:

```
User.findOne(id)
    .exec((err, user) => {
        Pets.find(_.pluck(user.pets, 'id'))
            .populate("toys")
            .exec((err, petsWithToys) => {
                 user.pets = petsWithToys;
                 return res.ok({ user: user });
             });
    });
```

When I look at the response in the client I don't see the toys array inside the pet.

I thought maybe this was due to overriding the `toJSON` function in my `User` model but even when removing it I get the same behavior.

Also, I've found out that if I assign the values to a new property that is not defined in the model, I do see the values at the client. I.e. if I do

```
user.petsNew = petsWithToys;
```

I will see the fully populated property.

I've seen the documentation of `toObject` where is says it removes instance methods ([here](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/master/reference/waterline/records/toObject.md)) but I am not sure why the collection is considered a method and don't understand how after changing the value it is still removed.

Any comments/explanations/workarounds?

P.S. Tried to step through the code but can't step into `toObject`...

Comment: When you set a breakpoint on the `user.pets = petsWithToys;` line and inspect `user`, does it have `toys`?

Comment: What version of Lodash are you using? since v.4 `_.pluck` is being removed in favor of `_.map`.
See [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35136306/what-happened-to-lodash-pluck)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - yes, there is - it is only removed in toJSON/toObject call. It seems the suggestion in the answer below would work (need to test).

Comment: @ZuzuSoftman - I'm using 3.10.x which is bundled with sails.js - thanks for the tip though - I'll look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `user = user.toJSON();` before `user.pets = petsWithToys;`

Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/43500017/1435132